# SSH tunnel to Cassandra ports failing

Tags: cassandra

I am having cassandra community edition 3.11.13 running on private subnet in AWS. I am trying to create tunnel to the cassandra using below commands.

```
ssh -vvv -N -L 9042:cass-ip:9042 username@jumphost-ip
ssh -vvv -N -L 9160:cass-ip:9160 username@jumphost-ip
```

Now with nc command i can see connection is fine.

```
nc -dvzw50 localhost 9160
Connection to localhost 9160 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

nc -dvzw50 localhost 9042
Connection to localhost 9042 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

But when i try to run cqlsh localhost it is giving me operation timed out.
Below is the output when i run ssh tunnel command.

```
debug2: channel 2: chan_shutdown_write: shutdown() failed for fd 7: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Any help is appreciated

Upon debugging narrow down to storage part.
I am having volume mounted as data directory, if i unmount it and set data_directory to default location it is working, but not with mount partition. I can see all the permissions on mount partition are exactly as same as default location.

Comment: Are you making any Thrift based client connections?  If not, there’s no need to do anything with 9160.  Everything should be done over 9042.

Comment: @Aaron yes but that comes later part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My bad  fixed out issue finally. So we have cqlsh.py file where it requires tuning for 2 parameters.

```
DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 60
DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 60
```

Ideal values are set to 10 seconds, after increasing timeout value to 60 i am able to connect without any issues

Answer (score 0):

I noted you mentioned that when you leave the default configuration for the data directory, your setup works:

```
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
```

but when you configure it to point to another mount/volume, you are not able to connect to the Cassandra instance.

This indicates to me that the issue isn't with the SSH tunnel but that the Cassandra instance isn't running.

You need to review the Cassandra startup messages in `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` for clues as to why it doesn't start when you reconfigure the data directory. My best guess is that you have not specified the correct path so Cassandra cannot find the mount point.

Once you fix that, you can try to start Cassandra and test the connectivity via the SSH tunnel. Cheers!

Comment: No there is no issue with the path. with in private network my application is working fine. Issue coming at tunnel to local. 
One more thing i figured out is, i have like 30 keyspaces in the cluster i have dropped few of them then tunnel started working fine even in local.